# How to specify searching sequence in fields in solr?

Tags: solr, lucene

I am a newbie for Solr.

I have few fields.

1. Title
2. Abstract
3. Desc

I want `solr` to first check if it matches the `Title`, then in `Abstract` and finally in `Desc`.

I Googled and found suggestions to **boost** factors in `qf` field. But with this I don't see the result what I wish for.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I've provided my best guess, but without you explaining what's wrong with the results, or providing the query you aren't satisfied with, or anything else, it really is just a guess.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to match in title, and only search in abstract if you find nothing, I would just run separate searches.  Search for titles, if you find nothing, move on to the next query.

If you want to get matches to all three fields at once, with Title matches at the top, boosting is the right way to go, and the `qf` parameter is the probably the easiest approach.  Perhaps the problem is you aren't defining large enough boosts.  There are a lot of statistics that influence score, boost being only one of them, so if you want your boost to dominate scoring behavior in this way, *big differences count*!  Perhaps something like:

```
q=solr&defType=dismax&qf=title^1000.0+abstract^10.0+desc^0.1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am try a bit more with your solution y using function query. Lets see, if that works I'll accept your solution.